# What is up with this in ColdFusion's DecimalFormat() function? How do I get the correct result?

Tags: coldfusion, decimalformat

```
<cfset number1 = 20.5/80 * 100 />
<cfset number2 = 18.125 />
<cfset number3 = 6.875 />

<cfoutput>
DecimalFormat(#number1#): #DecimalFormat(number1)#<br />
DecimalFormat(#number2#): #DecimalFormat(number2)#<br />
DecimalFormat(#number3#): #DecimalFormat(number3)#
</cfoutput>
```

**OUTPUTS:**

DecimalFormat(25.625): 25.62

DecimalFormat(18.125): 18.13

DecimalFormat(6.875): 6.88

**RATHER THAN OUTPUTING:**

DecimalFormat(25.625): 25.63

DecimalFormat(18.125): 18.13

DecimalFormat(6.875): 6.88

It seems that a variable that is the result of a mathematical calculation makes DecimalFormat() behave differently. Any quick fix, without digging into java?

Comment: also, NumberFormat(number1,".__") does the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is not `DecimalFormat()`, but the typical floating-point rounding errors.

see: [`PrecisionEvaluate()`](http://www.cfquickdocs.com/cf8/#PrecisionEvaluate)

Comment: Shouldn't be any floating-point errors, all of these numbers can be expressed exactly as a base-2 floating-point number. (0.625 = 5/8, 0.125 = 1/8, 0.875 = 7/8.  Since 8 is a power of 2, there would be no roundoff error.)  I'm assuming a `double` or `float` is used under the covers...

Comment: that said, i can't think of any reason for the results he's seeing

Comment: number1 = PrecisionEvaluate(20.5/80 * 100) will get you 25.62500000000000000000 -> 25.63

Comment: using PrecisionEvaluate() in calculations makes the DecimalFormat() function behave more consistantly! :)

Answer (score 2):

DecimalFormat is a formatting function. Not a Mathematical function. Its job is not to round your number for you, unfortunately CF lacks good mathematical functions for decimals so you will have to write your own.

Here is one someone wrote on the CF livedocs page for round():

```
 <cffunction name="roundDecimal" returntype="numeric"> 
     <cfargument name="num" type="numeric" required="yes"> 
     <cfargument name="decimal" type="numeric" default="2" required="no"> 

     <cfreturn round(num*10^decimal)/10^decimal /> 
  </cffunction>
```

Comment: True, it is a formatting function, and I was using it for output, but needed it to function consistently across values whether calculated or not. But, good solution if you need to round numbers for other means...

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix would be to change line 1 to `number1 = NumberFormat(20.5/80 * 100,'9.999')`

Answer (score -1):

Please see the CF documentation [NumberFormat](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/7/htmldocs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=ColdFusion_Documentation&file=00000591.htm) and do a page search on round to see some specific information.