# Coldfusion 10 NumberFormat bug

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

can someone please explain why total_a and total_b show different results after NumberFormat is applied? Very unpredictable behavior.

```
<cfset total_a = 60.50 />
<cfset total_a = total_a*1.19 />
<cfoutput>#total_a# before round up<br /></cfoutput><!--- 71.995 --->
<cfset total_a = NumberFormat(total_a,'9.99') />
<cfoutput>#total_a# after round up<br /><br /></cfoutput><!--- 71.99 --->

<cfset total_b = 71.995 />
<cfoutput>#total_b# before round up<br /></cfoutput><!--- 71.995 --->
<cfset total_b = NumberFormat(total_b,'9.99') />
<cfoutput>#total_b# after round up<br /></cfoutput><!--- 72.00 --->
```

Comment: I see exactly the same behavior in MS SQL so I believe there is something I do not know about decimal/float numbers...

Comment: Yeah this is not a bug with CF but a floating point rounding error. Can be found on a few platforms. Some explanations here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428173/what-is-up-with-this-in-coldfusions-decimalformat-function-how-do-i-get-the

Comment: Found how to "solve" it  - change line 2 to "total_a = NumberFormat(total_a*1.19,'9.999')". But I still wonder what happened. Some invisible decimal places?

Comment: Not sure what search phrase you used, but a quick search should have turned up a *ton* of threads explaining CF uses floating point numbers ( or `Double`) by default. One example is the link haxtbh posted and another: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Also, [do not always trust what you see on the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18594912/104223). Often it is biased towards user friendly output, rather than accuracy.  If you output `total_a.toString()` you will see the Double value is actually 71.99499999999999.